# Зависает установка Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS в VirtualBox 6.1.16

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

При установке Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS на VirtualBox 6.1.16, установка зависает (см. видео):
https://youtu.be/V_74KQ1Mctg.

Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Как её решить?

Вот параметры системы
[image]

Comment: Во время загрузки убунты нажмите Esc и почитайте логи

Comment: Попробовал, но логи не отображаются.

Comment: Похоже на проблему с графоном. Давай итерационно. Сначала качни `netboot` редакцию и воткни просто бубен без графики. Потом сделай снапшот и накати чё ты там хотел - гномшелл?

Comment: @donRumata Спасибо за ответ, но он крайне сложен для моего понимания так как я новичок в администрировании.

Comment: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso
Вот это качаешь и ставишь БЕЗ графики. Поставишь - отпишись.

Comment: @donRumata Спасибо за ответ! Всё сделал по вашим инструкциям, но увы ничего не заработало. Вот изображение с консолью где у меня всё зависает:
https://ibb.co/QKcGTJv

Comment: Попробуй "Интефейс паравиртуализации" переключить на "Отсутствует".

Comment: @donRumata По вашим инструкциям отключил "Интерфейс паравиртуализации", теперь консоль зависает с таким видом: https://ibb.co/KNsRRTF

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503733/136975

Comment: @donRumata Сделал всё по присланной вами инструкции, а именно изменил "Графический контроллер" на "VBoxVGA" и выделил на процессор 2 ядра вместо одного. Хотелось бы заметить, что при изменении графического контроллера VirtualBox написал, что "Обнаружены неправильные графические настройки". Система к моему большому сожалению так и не запустилась вот такой код ошибки я имею теперь: https://ibb.co/9y3D1cm.

Comment: Так, у тебя хостовая система какая? Винда или линукс?

Comment: @donRumata Хостовая система Windows 10 Pro 1909.

Comment: В общем этим скриптом я постоянно создаю себе виртуалки именн под бубен. Всё отлично пашет уже несколько лет. Поменяй имена переменных, а `vboxmanage` работает одинаково везде. https://gist.github.com/don-rumata/b0c93611e334792abb445b222be638d3

Comment: @donRumata не подскажите как активировать этот скрипт на Windows?

Comment: Ну если есть вопросы в таком кмк простом коде, то просто прочти каменты и сделай как там написано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой ответ был найден в процессе решения ошибки в программе *VMware*.

Но после этого и **VirtualBox** заработал.

**Решение**:

1. Открыть cmd от имени администратора.
2. Прописать команду: **bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off**

Источники:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEU4n2-n_U8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjCVYJBfEQ4